# Subset and Loop to create a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

Good Morning,

I have the following dataset:

print(df)

```
Product_code   Quantity_in_stock   
    01                4                     
    02                1                   
    01                2                   
    03                6                   
    02                9                    
...
```

I would like to create an additional column "Average_quantity", using Pandas, equals to the **average "Quantity_in_stock"** of that **specific** **product**; for instance:

```
Product_code   Quantity_in_stock    Average_quantity
    01                4                    3  
    02                1                    5
    01                2                    3
    03                6                    6
    02                9                    5
...
```

I tried:

```
for i in df["Product_code"]:
    df["Average_quantity"] = np.mean(df["Quantity_in_stock"])
```

But it reports the same average quantity of the whole set, not the one of that **specific product code**

How Can I solve it?

Comment: I think need `df['Average_quantity'] = df.groupby(['Product_code'])['Quantity_in_stock'].transform('mean')`, it is dupe.

Comment: It works, thank you :) @jezrael

Comment: You are welcome!